# Override install_requires version

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a Python package that is it used as a library and as an executable. So I wanted the library no to have the fixed versions, but when installing the package as an executable I wanted to have the dependencies fixed. The issue is that there is a common version between the library and the bin, but it read the bin. So I have something like:

```
setup(
    install_requires=['six'],
    extra_requires={
        'bin'=['six==1.0.0'],
)
```

But if I do

```
pip install foobar[bin]
```

It install any version of `six`.

So I wanted to know if there was a way to override the install_requires version based on extra_requires